# Nopcommerce using data from model in view as placeholder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

So I would like to display data in my admin tab view, which is not null as a placeholder value.

I though maybe something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmazonProductSKU, placeholder = model.AmazonProductSKU)
```

Or this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmazonProductSKU, new { @placeholder = T(model.AmazonProductSKU) })
```

But it breaks my tab.

Everything works, so model updates database etc.

Anyone have any ideas of how this might be accomplished, is it even possible?

Thanks peeps

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sku, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Amazon Product SKU Here" } })
```

If it comes from model use `placeholder = Model.AmazonProductSKU`.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sku, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Model.AmazonProductSKU } })
```

For resource string, you cannot use it as `T(model.AmazonProductSKU)`, because `T` is custom helper in nopCommerce and accepting a string argument into it.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sku, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = T("AmazonProductSKU.Placeholder ") } })
```

And add that resource string from the admin panel.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Div, thanks for the help. I was hoping to use the value of model.AmazonProductSKU as the placeholder. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, It's not good idea, but in that case what will be the value of  `AmazonProductSKU ` ?

Comment: It will be the value from the database

Comment: Yes, It's possible, I've show you in the answer *If it comes from model use placeholder = Model.AmazonProductSKU* and also updated the answer.

Comment: Ok I will look at it tomorrow morning, about to leave the office.

Comment: @WebDevGuy: Hope this works, if so please accept the answer so other can find it useful :)